# Laravel : Amazon Web Service change time zone as UTC

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, datetime, laravel-5.5

I uploaded my laravel application on `aws server`, In my `php.ini` file set `timezone as UTC` also in `config/app.php` set `'timezone' => 'UTC'`.That all did not work for me so I also set in `.env` file `APP_TIMEZONE=UTC` after all that I run command for `clear cache and config` but at last this all are not working for me .

When I check

`{{ date_default_timezone_get() . ' => ' . date('e') . ' => ' . date('T') }}`

I am getting `Asia/Calcutta => Asia/Calcutta => IST` in server. I expect `UTC => UTC => UTC`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you restart your php/apache?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra yes  i restart it several time